# Lie Or lay ELA Question

Tags: verbs, lie-lay-lain-laid

Which one is it?

> Please lay/lie your dog on the bench.

I think it's lay but I'm not sure

Comment: Neither, for a dog, but I might *lay* my towel on a beach.

Comment: ... although there _are_ non-sentient-referent senses of 'dog' (including dead ones).

Comment: A Dormeo mattress ad says, "As soon as you _lay_ on the Puffy bed mattress you will feel an instantaneous relief." I suppose, if you're an ostrich...